# HealthIndicator with custom url or seperate multiple HealthIndicators

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

in my application, I have multiple HealthIndicators. Some of them (external services) are being implemented in this manner:

```java
private static HealthIndicator createHealthIndicator(VersionedService service) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                VersionInfo version = service.getCurrentVersion(); // this calls external service, which is slow
                return Health.up()
                        .withDetail("version", version.getTechnicalName())
                        .build();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return Health.down().build();
            }
        };
    }
```

I am reaching health endpoint using `.../api/actuator/health`. The problem I have is, I have **some** external Services, which takes ages to retrieve information form all services. And if a service is responding really slow, I am receiving the response very slowly.

What is the best practice for this purpose?

1- I can use `/api/actuator/health/<service-name>` endpoints separately in the frontend to retrieve health checks for each component. But since I have multiple services (and a couple of them could be removed/added later), this is somehow hard-coded approach and I need to send multiple calls to the backend. In other words, I don't want to send `.../api/actuator/health/service1`, `.../api/actuator/health/service2`, `.../api/actuator/health/service3`, ... , `.../api/actuator/health/some-external-service1`, `.../api/actuator/health/some-external-service2`.

2- If I can somehow override the url of those external Services, I can manually call them from the front-end and at least I will have many of the health check results combined in a request, and slow ones separately. In other words, calling the normal health-check endpoint (`.../api/actuator/health`) will give me all health-checks except the ones that I override in the backend and I will call slow-ones `../api/actuator/health-<some-slow-external-service>` from front-end manually. The problem with this approach is I don't know how to override health-check url for a given `HealthIndicator`.

3- Any other recommendations?

As a side note, I am not using reactive

Comment: What do you mean combine them? Are you just looking to change the endpoints? Did you look at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.monitoring.customizing-management-server-context-path)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider what I mean is I want to change a specific healthcheck's endpoint. So, assume I have 10 endpoints, 2 of them I want to change. I want to reach 8 of them using `.../api/actuator/health`, the other 2, I want a custom thing, so that my endpoint call will be short for regular health checks. I don't know how to override a specific health checks endpoint. Right now, calling `.../api/actuator/health` gives all health checks. I want to exclude slow ones from there, and call them separately, manually, by overriding their endpoint urls.